# How do I store all the information in a class to a single text file?

Tags: java, text

I have this User class which can be inputted with information.  However, once the main method is shut down, the information is lost.  I was wondering how I could store all the information into a text file in the structure as follows.

username

number of messages in the inbox

message1 sender

message1 receiver

message1 subject

message1 body

message2 sender

message2 receiver

message2 subject

message2 body
...

message class

```
public class Message {      
  // the properties of a message
  private String sender;
  private String receiver;
  private String subject;
  private String body;

  // all property values are known at creation of the message; so initialize
  public Message (String s, String r, String sub, String b)
  {
    sender = s;
    receiver = r;
    subject = sub;
    body = b;
  }

  // any nice format of printing the names and the values of the properties will do
  public void printMsg()
  {
    System.out.println("Sender: " + sender);
    System.out.println("Receiver: " + receiver);
    System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
    System.out.println("Message: " + body);
  }

  // what follows are basic getter methods

  public String getSender()
  {
    return sender;
  }

  public String getReceiver()
  {
    return receiver;
  }

  public String getSubject()
  {
    return subject;
  }

  public String getBody()
  {
    return body;
  }

}
```

user class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class Userlist
  {

    private ArrayList<User> users; 
    private int numUsers;

    public Userlist()
    {
      users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    public User findUser(String username)
    {
      for (User i : users)
      {
        if (i.userName.equals(username))
          return i;
      }
      return null;
    }

    public void addUser(User u)
    {
      if (findUser(u.userName) != null)
        System.out.println("User already exists");
      else
      {
       users.add(u);
       numUsers++;
      }
    }

    public int getNumUsers()
    {
       return this.numUsers;
    }

    public User getUser(int i)
    {
      if (i>=users.length)
        return null;
      else
        return users.get(i-1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read and write text files?

Comment: Does it have to be a text file? If not, then you could serialize and deserialize quite easily, but that's in binary format, not human-readable.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to store the info into a textfile and next time when I open it, the method would read the textfile and add in the appropriate information. And yes it does have to readable by humans.

Comment: Serialize it somehow, using Java serialization, JSON, or XML serialization.  JSON is generally the most readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technique 1: Human Readable Format**

If you need to store it in human readable format , you have the following options :

1) Store it as JSON (You can look into [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library, its fairly simple to use)

2) Store as XML

3) You need to write the logic to convert the object into string representation (which might be a lot of work)

**Technique 2 : Binary File**

The process of storing contents/state of an Object to a file is called as Serialization. You can look at the following tutorial  : [Java - Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Before your main method exits you can Serialize the objects to some file by serializing User Objects. Also when you are serializing the object of user A, you can serialize all the messages for that user.

First you need to declare all the classes that you want to serialize as Serializable :

```
public class UserList implements Serializable
{
}

public class Message implements Serializable
{
}
```

Then for serializing/deserializing you can use the following code  :

```
FileOutputStream  fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

UserList userList ; // assume this is the object to be serialized
out.writeObject(userList); // serializes the object
```

For getting the object back from the file (de-serialize) :

```
FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
userList = (UserList) in.readObject();
```

Comment: But my understanding is that Java serialization is not human-readable.